# Importrange access permission in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to access data from another spreadsheet using IMPORTRANGE function, But every-time it says that I am not allowed to access source sheet.

- I am owner of destination sheet using IMPORTRANGE function.
- I am editor of source sheet (Owner is my friend)

Owner of source sheet is unable to find way to allow access to me.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 8 times. The question doesn't include enough details. Please add if both accounts belong to the same type and if both belong to the same domain. The spreadsheet-sharing settings are the formula and the URL (you might want to create a pair of demo spreadsheets for demo purposes).

Answer (score 1):

**First**, make sure that the `spreadsheet_url` parameter is correct. You can test it by copy-pasting it (omitting the double quotes) in the browser's address bar and pressing **Enter**. If the URL opens that way, it should also work in `importrange()`.

**Second**, make sure that the range_string is correct. You can test it in the *source* spreadsheet by choosing **Insert > New sheet** and inserting a test formula in cell `A1` there. To create the test formula, copy-paste the range string (omitting the double quotes) in an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

`={ 'Data sheet'!A1:D42 }`

**Third**, if both `importrange()` parameters pass the test, confirm that you have clicked the <kbd>Allow access</kbd> button that shows when you hover over the `importrange()` formula cell.

If you do not see the <kbd>Allow access</kbd> button, try authorizing the `importrange()` formula through a temporary formula cell. In the destination spreadsheet, put this in a free cell:

`=importrange("DUaK5OtSNq7D2r9h5b2JtU_9FsNDu08L_jlL1uuNPkwc", "A1")`

...where the long string of letters and numbers is the spreadsheet ID. You can find it in the source spreadsheet's address bar between `/d/` and `/edit`. Note that the ID will have to be in double quotes.

Chances are that the new formula cell will display a red corner flag. Hover over the the formula cell and click <kbd>Allow access</kbd>. After that, your existing `importrange()` formula should start working as well.