# Importrange access permission in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use `IMPORTRANGE()` but I run into trouble with permissions even though

- I'm the owner of the data source
- I'm editor of the data destination

I get the "You don't have permission to access this sheet" (I'm translating from Spanish, not sure what the actual message is in English). I've read [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155077/importrange-access-permission-in-google-spreadsheet) and followed the instructions, i.e., both the `spreadsheet url` and the range string are valid. However, no "allow access" message appears.

**Edit**
As I'm unable to use `IMPORTRANGE()`, I've tried to move the specific sheet with the data into the spreadsheet where I wanted to import it. This is not working either. I get the message "You cannot copy this sheet into an Office file" (again, this is my translation of the Spanish message). I'm guessing my problems have to do with the fact that both the data source and its destination were originally created as Excel files and then moved to Drive. Is it possible to change their format so that they become Sheets files?

**Edit 2** I've saved the worksheets in Google Sheets format and `IMPORTRANGE()` works properly.

Comment: Are you using the same account to access both spreadsheets? That could be the problem, but if you could share a link to your spreadsheet then we could diagnose it directly.